# Do Shell Script From Apple Script Requires Terminal To Have Full Disk Access - But It Already Has Full Disk Access

Tags: macos, terminal, applescript, admin, privileges

I am making an Apple Script app that will change my Time Machine backup configuration. The Apple script command is simply:

```
set ThePath to quoted form of "/Users/AndrewDesktop/Documents/AppleScripts/Time Machine Control Scripts/Do Not Backup iTunes Library.sh"`
--do shell script "bash " & ThePath with administrator privileges
```

Right now I have all of my shell commands commented. Even so when I run the apple script I am prompted for my password and then I get an error:

```
error "bash: /Users/AndrewDesktop/Documents/AppleScripts/Time Machine Control Scripts/Do Not Backup iTunes Library.sh: Operation not permitted" number 126
```

As all of the shell commands are commented I don't necessarily need the admin privileges. When I run the same Apple script command without admin privileges:

```
set ThePath to quoted form of "/Users/AndrewDesktop/Documents/AppleScripts/Time Machine Control Scripts/Do Not Backup iTunes Library.sh"
do shell script "bash " & ThePath
```

I do not get an error.

I decided to avoid having a separate shell file and tried to enter each exclusion as its own do shell script command in apple script like so:

```
do shell script "sudo tmutil addexclusion -v /Volumes/iTunes Library" with administrator privileges
```

But even this brute force method fails as I am given the maddening error:

```
error "tmutil: addexclusion requires Full Disk Access privileges.
To allow this operation, select Full Disk Access in the Privacy
tab of the Security & Privacy preference pane, and add Terminal
to the list of applications which are allowed Full Disk Access." number 80
```

Terminal already has full disk access and so does Script Editor! Even so I disabled and reenabled full disk access for both and no dice.

Any idea how to get root to work?

Ls -l from terminal of the .sh yields only:

```
-rwx------@ 1
```

Edit:
Red dance there is a tech note about `with administrator privileges` and sudo here: [TN2065](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2065/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003093-CH1-TNTAG1-HOW_DO_I_GET_ADMINISTRATOR_PRIVILEGES_FOR_A_COMMAND_). The note there seems to say that sudo is unnecessary when using apple script with adminstrator privileges. But changing my shell script to remove the sudo didn't work.

I just need to be able to run tmutil add/removeexclusion from apple script which requires sudo permissions. How do I do this?

Comment: `with administrator privileges` should not be used with `sudo`, and Terminal doesn't have anything to do with `do shell script`.  Could something else your script is doing need permissions?

Comment: ‘Do shell script’ and ‘with administrator privileges’ are commands in apple script to launch a shell script from apple script that uses sudo. Controlling Time Machine exclusions requires sudo. If I launch the script from an apple script app I can have the computer do thing when the app is quit at logout. I added some clarification to denote what was Apple script

Comment: Using `with administrator privileges` with `sudo` creates a security hole (see [TN2065](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2065/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003093-CH1-TNTAG1-HOW_DO_I_GET_ADMINISTRATOR_PRIVILEGES_FOR_A_COMMAND_), not sure if the current OSes are getting pickier.  `do shell script` doesn't automatically give everything permission - if there is something _else_ in the shell script that needs permission, you may need to add that.

Comment: when, in apple script I use `do shell script "bash " & ThePath` and in the shell script have `sudo tmutil addexclusion /Users/Theodore` I get the error "sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
sudo: a password is required". What is the correct method to call a shell script from apple script that requires sudo? Of course, directly in terminal I am prompted for my password. when I append `with administrator privieges` I am prompted to enter my password before getting an error.

Comment: I did append additional info to the end of the original question regarding removing sudo and using with admin

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the documents folder where both the apple script and the shell script are saved is protected. when I moved both scripts to user/Andrew the errors went away. I don't know how to get it to work when housed in the documents folder but moving out to somewhere else did work.